# Golang telnet аутентификация

Tags: golang, ssh, telnet

У меня есть несколько десятков `SSH тунелей` и мне каждый нужно проверить на валидность зная логин и пароль, как я могу это быстро сделать?

И вообще я не нашел нормальных библиотек Golang для реализации `SSH аутентификации`..

Comment: А эта не подходит? https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh

Comment: @nobody разве с ней можно проверять ssh тунели?

Comment: @nobody можете к ответу приложить пример?

Comment: https://github.com/dynport/gossh - пример там же